# How to extract URI from context in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to figure out a way of extracting the URI / URL from a content in my view; in Rails.

So far everything seems to be working but with glitches and I'm thinking because the source code isn't a clean URI but rather one that has extra stuff in it. So far in my view I have the following;

```
    <div id="social" class="facebook" data-url="<%= URI.extract(saved.content) %>">
```

Now that live above works but like I said with a glitch, because Facebook sometimes picks up the url and sometimes it doesn't. With the above line; I get the following source code results;

```
    <div id="social" class="facebook" data-url="[&quot;dealbook:&quot;, &quot;http://t.co/mUQOmLlLXG&quot;]">
```

`saved.content` has a message that can sometimes have a url in it;

Is there any way I can clean that up? so it get's picked up easier. It be awesome if the URI / URL was just printed out into `data-url=""` and not quotes, brackets, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
data-url="<%= URI.extract(saved.content).detect {|u| u.start_with? "http" } %>"
```

The reason is that `URI#extract` returns an array of matches; you can use `Enumerable#detect` to find the first one which matches the block, which in this case is the condition that the URL start with "http".

Comment: is there a way to do this detecting both http and https, just in case :) If I'm correct something like `{ |u| u.start_with? "http" || "https"} ` would work ??

Comment: I guess its not really needed since http in the detect part would also match https or httpy or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

```
# in saved model
 def content_url
   s = self.content.gsub(/&[0-9a-z]+;/i, ' ') # replace &xxx;(html symbol) with ' ' string
   URI.extract(s, ['http', 'https']).first
 end

#in view
<div id="social" class="facebook" data-url="<%= saved.content_url%>">
```

In saved model, define a method #content_url to extract url.

Comment: Code-only answers are auto-flagged as low quality and as such are discouraged on stackoverflow. In the future please embellish your answer with details and explain why it is a solution to the question. This helps other users.

Comment: @yxf any reason why you put this in the model? shouldn't that go into the controller and is it necessary to go that deep then just leaving it in the views?

Comment: @user2419316 #content is model accessor, #content_url is used to extract url from content. if you defined #content_url in controller? where? helper_method?. I think is better to defined in model. And defined in model keep code clean.